# Error in if (xc[i - 1] != 32 && xc[i] > 96 && xc[i] < 123) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

This is an error from a loop function of getting a contingency table from a dataset with 13 variables. The variables are factors but for this specific variable I get this error.

I was creating a contingency table and p-values from a dataset and got this error. I was expecting an output of a contingency table but instead I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there are missing values (i.e. NA) in xc. You could either filter out rows with missing values by doing

```
#If xc is a vector
xc<-xc[is.na(xc)]
#If xc is a column in dataframe df
df<-df[is.na(df$xc),]
```

or add an if statement to prevent the error

```
if(is.na(xc[i])| is.na(xc[i])){
  next
}else{
  if (xc[i - 1] != 32 && xc[i] > 96 && xc[i] < 123){
    ...
  }
}
```

This code does not add count if there is missing value in current or previous index.